# Is this correct way to set up .plist for required device capability?

Tags: xcode, plist, capability, video-camera

Will the following .plist entry PREVENT devices without a video camera from purchasing an app? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html):

> **UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities**
>
> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities (Array or Dictionary - iOS) lets iTunes and the App Store know which device-related features an application requires in order to run. iTunes and the mobile App Store use this list to prevent customers from installing applications on a device that does not support the listed capabilities.
>
> If you use an array, the presence of a given key indicates the corresponding feature is required. If you use a dictionary, you must specify a Boolean value for each key. If the value of this key is true, the feature is required. If the value of the key is false, the feature must not be present on the device. In both cases, omitting a key indicates that the feature is not required but that the application is able to run if the feature is present.

----------EDIT----------

This image is from the link above.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since it says "If you use an array, the presence of a given key indicates the corresponding feature is required", I think the above is correct. Could you please confirm the above image is correct for preventing the device from purchasing the app w/o a video camera? Thanks again.

Comment: It is correct. If you check out the link I provided - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html - you can see that the key you wrote in (video-camera) is correct. I added a photo in my post

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did check out the link you provided, but just wanted to make sure I had everything entered correctly in the .plist file. I haven't worked that much with .plist files in the past and I was hoping a more experienced pair of eyes could confirm that all's well with the .plist entry. Thanks very much!

Comment: No problem. Property lists can also be used for storing data, just so you know.